# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una matriz entre dos activity en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Tengo el problema que no puedo enviar una matriz de dos dimensiones de un activity a otro. Puedo hacerlo con un vector pero necesito que sea una matriz y la verdad que sigo obteniendo errores. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

**En el primer Activity:**

```
int matriz [][] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}};
i = new Intent (this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("numeros", matriz);
startActivity(i);
```

**En mi segundo Activity**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int[] matrizB = extras.getIntArray("numeros");
```

El problema que tengo es que si defino a matrizB como "matrizb [][]", obtengo un error ya que espera que matrizB sea un vector[]. Estuve probando con otros métodos que ofrece Android pero seguía teniendo errores.
Nose realmente si existe algún método que me permite obtener esta matriz o si es necesario definir mi matriz diferente y hacerlo de alguna otra forma.

Cualquier respuesta se agradece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recupera el dato como un object y luego haz un casting a `int[][]`

```
int[][] matrizB = (int[][]) extras.get("numeros");
```

**Actualización:**

En la activity2 reemplaza:

```
int[] matrizB = extras.getIntArray("numeros");
```

Por:

```
int[][] matrizB = (int[][]) extras.get("numeros");
```

Comment: ¿Podés ser mas especifico?¿Qué debo poner en cada activity? Estoy empezando con Android y algunos conceptos no los tengo muy claros.

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!! Funciono perfecto.